# Setting Images and Name in Collection View swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

So im trying to set images and their name in a collection view what ive achieved is that ive set the names but im unable to set the images to that collection view

im setting up the array of names and icons here

```
let dataArray = ["Home", "Appointment", "Teleconsultation", "Lab", "Pharmacy", "Registration", "Careers", "Utilities","Feedback"]
    var icons : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "appointment.png")!, UIImage(named: "telehealth.png")!, UIImage(named: "lab.png")!, UIImage(named: "pharmacy.png")!, UIImage(named: "labreports.png")!, UIImage(named: "laborder.png")!, UIImage(named: "pharmacyorder.png")!, UIImage(named: "logout.png")!]
```

and then im trying to load that up to my collection view using this

im getting the names in the collection view but not the image
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                  return dataArray.count
              }

```
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)  as! ItemCell
              cell.setData(text: self.dataArray[indexPath.row])
              cell.setData(UIImageView: self.dataArray[indexPath.row])


              return cell
          }
```

This line gives error when i use it that says : Incorrect argument label in call (have 'UIImageView:', expected 'text:')

```
          cell.setData(UIImageView: self.dataArray[indexPath.row])
```

my ItemCell Class

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
            }

    func setData(text: String) {
        self.textLabel.text = text



    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show your `ItemCell` class? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: self.collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")

Comment: I don't mean the line where you register the cell. I mean the `ItemCell` _class_. Also, you should [edit] your question to include necessary information.

Comment: i added my itemCell class and edited it to my main post

Comment: At least you have to get the image from the proper array: `self.icons[indexPath.row]`. This is a pretty good example why you should not use multiple arrays as data source. Where is the image view in the cell? The syntax `cell.setData(UIImageView:...` is pointless.

Comment: ahhhh actually im new to this and im still trying to find out ways to iOS im a web developer and for some reason i have to work on this for my workplace. Thankyou for guiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the error states clearly that you don't have a method `setData(UIImageView:` in your `ItemCell` class. Add one to the `ItemCell` class that accepts type `UIImage` and implement the method to set the image to the imageView and you're good to go. Before that make sure the cell has an `UIImageView` added and it's connected to the `@IBOutlet` in the `ItemCell` for `imageView`. Here's an example:

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func setData(image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Note: You should modify your naming conventions to some extend too.